# push public key on multiple server using root account but under different user

Tags: bash, public-key

I am trying to push some public keys on a whole bunch of servers using the root account but I wanna put those new keys under 'postgres' user.

I'm doing this:

```
$ cat new_dba_keys.pub | ssh -l root 10.224.1.16 "su - postgres |cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
-bash: line 2: ssh-rsa: command not found
-bash: line 4: ssh-rsa: command not found
```

As you can see, it will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `su - postgres | cat ...` you can use `su - postgres -c "cat ..."` and will place text in postgre's directory:

```
cat new_dba_keys.pub | ssh -l root 10.224.1.16 "su - postgres -c \"cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys\""
```

Comment: Noope. That doesn't doesn't work. -bash: |cat: No such file or directory

Comment: In fact, you get error messages from line 2 and 4 `-bash: line 2: ssh-rsa: command not found`, while file .pub should be just one line. Have you checked the file to see if it has extra content?

Comment: the file is good mate, I've fixed it in the mean time. Actually, they get pushed bu they end up under /root/.ssh/authorized_keys :( (I want them under postgres user

Comment: Edit made. Instead of `su - postgres | cat ...` you can use `su - postgres -c "cat ..."` and will place text in postgre's directory.

Comment: Haha it was a team work! I edit first answer so it just appears the good answer.